# Problem with RODBC installation in Ubuntu with R 3.5.1

Tags: r, odbc

The thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/283272/problem-with-rodbc-installation-in-ubuntu) about RODBC is old, about 7 years old, their solution about installing `r-cran-odbc` and `libiodbc2-dev` do not work. As of R 3.5.1, I am getting the same error as 7 years ago

```
install.packages("RODBC", keep_outputs = T)

configure: error: "ODBC headers sql.h and sqlext.h not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library/RODBC’
```

despite having the mentioned packages installed. So

### **How to get the RODBC installed in Ubuntu as of R 3.5.1 (latest versions of R and Ubuntu)?**

---

*Minimal reproducible base (Dockerfile)*

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/minimal-notebook
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

USER root

# R pre-requisites
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    fonts-dejavu \
    tzdata \
    libiodbc2-dev \
    r-cran-rodbc \
    gfortran \
    gcc && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER $NB_UID

# R packages
RUN conda install --quiet --yes \
    'r-base=3.5.1' \
    'r-irkernel=0.8*' \
    'r-plyr=1.8*' \
    'r-devtools=1.13*' \
    'r-tidyverse=1.2*' \
    'r-shiny=1.2*' \
    'r-rmarkdown=1.11*' \
    'r-forecast=8.2*' \
    'r-rsqlite=2.1*' \
    'r-reshape2=1.4*' \
    'r-nycflights13=1.0*' \
    'r-caret=6.0*' \
    'r-rcurl=1.95*' \
    'r-crayon=1.3*' \
    'r-randomforest=4.6*' \
    'r-htmltools=0.3*' \
    'r-sparklyr=0.9*' \
    'r-htmlwidgets=1.2*' \
    'r-hexbin=1.27*' && \
    conda clean -tipsy && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR
```

where the following packages `libiodbc2-dev` and `r-cran-rodbc` won't resolve the issue.

*Specs*

```
$ uname -a
Linux 370485a13e40 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Jun 6 16:55:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*sql.h is located in the following*

```
$ apt-file sql.h

libdballe-dev: /usr/include/dballe/sql/sql.h
libiodbc2-dev: /usr/include/iodbc/sql.h
libmailutils-dev: /usr/include/mailutils/sql.h
libwine-dev: /usr/include/wine/windows/sql.h
libwine-development-dev: /usr/include/wine-development/wine/windows/sql.h
mingw-w64-common: /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sql.h
mingw-w64-i686-dev: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/sql.h
mingw-w64-x86-64-dev: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sql.h
pike7.8-core: /usr/lib/pike7.8/include/sql.h
pike8.0-core: /usr/lib/pike8.0/include/sql.h
unixodbc-dev: /usr/include/sql.h
```

and

```
# apt-file search /sqlext.h
libiodbc2-dev: /usr/include/iodbc/sqlext.h
libwine-dev: /usr/include/wine/windows/sqlext.h
libwine-development-dev: /usr/include/wine-development/wine/windows/sqlext.h
mingw-w64-common: /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/sqlext.h
mingw-w64-i686-dev: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/sqlext.h
mingw-w64-x86-64-dev: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/sqlext.h
unixodbc-dev: /usr/include/sqlext.h
```

Comment: Consider R's `odbc` package that adheres to R's DBI standard among the other  APIs in DBI family: `ROracle`, `RMySQL`, `RSQLite`, `RPostgreSQL` even `rjdbc`. This is a robust well-maintained, more updated library than `RODBC`.

Answer (score 1):

The missing headers problem can be solved by installing the `r-rodbc` package from conda such that

```
RUN conda install --quiet --yes \
    'r-base=3.5.1' \
    'r-rodbc=1.3*' \
```

and then after that you will get the following error

```
hecking for library containing SQLTables... no
configure: error: "no ODBC driver manager found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RODBC’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library/RODBC’
* restoring previous ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library/RODBC’
```

for which you need `r-cran-odbc`, `unixodbc` and 'unixodbc-dev' (just unixodbc is not enough) from apt so your Dockerfile becomes

```
# Copyright (c) Jupyter Development Team.
# Distributed under the terms of the Modified BSD License.
ARG BASE_CONTAINER=jupyter/minimal-notebook
FROM $BASE_CONTAINER

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

USER root

# R pre-requisites
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    fonts-dejavu \
    tzdata \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    r-cran-rodbc \
    gfortran \
    gcc && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER $NB_UID

# R packages
RUN conda install --quiet --yes \
    'r-base=3.5.1' \
    'r-rodbc=1.3*' \
    'unixodbc=2.3.*' \
    'r-irkernel=0.8*' \
    'r-plyr=1.8*' \
    'r-devtools=1.13*' \
    'r-tidyverse=1.2*' \
    'r-shiny=1.2*' \
    'r-rmarkdown=1.11*' \
    'r-forecast=8.2*' \
    'r-rsqlite=2.1*' \
    'r-reshape2=1.4*' \
    'r-nycflights13=1.0*' \
    'r-caret=6.0*' \
    'r-rcurl=1.95*' \
    'r-crayon=1.3*' \
    'r-randomforest=4.6*' \
    'r-htmltools=0.3*' \
    'r-sparklyr=0.9*' \
    'r-htmlwidgets=1.2*' \
    'r-hexbin=1.27*' && \
    conda clean -tipsy && \
    fix-permissions $CONDA_DIR
```